# How do we write free body diagram for an object that is rebounding?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, time, velocity, free-body-diagram

How do we write free body diagram for an object that is rebounding?

Here's an illustrated example

[image]

Let us assume that the object has an initial force.

So, I want to draw free body diagram for each condition in order to see in how many seconds it took KLM. I'm also assuming that the object hits the point M.

**EDIT:** My main goal is to obtain time duration between KLM

Comment: A free body diagram is drawn for a specific moment in time. You can draw one for the situation at K, one at L and one at M. This cannot be used to find the falling duration, though, so I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking.

Comment: @Steeven I was going to draw free body diagram to know falling duration. If drawing free body diagram will not help, what should we use?

Comment: It will help but it will not be enough. You need more information to solve this, such as the duration that the initial force is exerted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: imagine slope as horizontal surface]

we can imagine slope as horizontal surface so we consider that velocity make angle theta with horizontal surface and acceleration due to gravity become a=-gcos theta .here, - signs shows downward direction. now, you can calculate time as normal projectile motion problem!!!